# How to make a radio button an image in ASP.NET webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make a basic form that uses asp.net RadioButtons for 5 different smiley faces. I want to remove the RadioButton default look and use an image that gets a border when it is selected. So far I have been avoiding jQuery and I was hoping that it could be done with only asp.net and c# code. This is the general code for each RadioButton so far

```
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="Exceeded" GroupName="experience" />
<label for="Exceeded">
    <img src="Images/Exceeded.png" />
</label>
```

Comment: You're only going to be able to do this with HTML and javascript, bound to something in the back using AJAX. Unfortunately you can't change the asp.net radiobutton control to be a custom image. Why are you avoiding jQuery?

Comment: Mostly for learning purposes. I thought their may have been some UI controls that I missed or misunderstood because there is so many that could do this easily.